# TypeError al Sumar dias a una fecha con Python

Tags: python

En el siguiente código intento sumar 365 días a una fecha que recupero de una **BBDD SQLITE** con formato **string** y la guardo en la variable **fechaUltimaCalibracion** con valor **"2019-10-7"** pero me da error. La salida en el terminal es la siguiente:

```
2019-10-07 time.struct_time(tm_year=2019, tm_mon=10, tm_mday=7, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=280, tm_isdst=-1) Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)   File "c:/Users/Gorbe/OneDrive/Documentos/myDQO/Temperas2.py", line 631, in ventanaEstadoSensor
    prox=mifecha+datetime.timedelta(days=365) TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "datetime.timedelta") to tuple
```

El código es el siguiente:

```
import time
import calendar
import datetime

  mifecha=time.strptime(fechaUltimaCalibracion,"%Y-%m-%d")


  print (fechaUltimaCalibracion)  #imprime correctamente la fecha según se ve

  print(mifecha)

  prox=mifecha+datetime.timedelta(days=365)  # esto da error
  print (prox)
  proximLabel=Label(campos,  text="Próxima calibración en: "+str(prox)+" días")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`time.strptime`  devuelve una "tupla"

tienes que usar `datetime.datetime.strptime(fechaUltimaCalibracion,"%Y-%m-%d")`

Answer (score 0):

Estás intentando hacer operaciones en un `struct_time` de la biblioteca `time` con un `timedelta` de la biblioteca `datetime`. No son compatibles, si vas a operar con datetime, debes hacerlo sobre otro elemento de datetime. Para esto, solo basta con convertir el que ya tienes:

```
dt = datetime.datetime(*mifecha[:6])
prox = dt+datetime.timedelta(days=365)
```

Comment: Eso es, gracias